# Trying to run AutoIt file from Python

Tags: python, autoit, os.system

I am trying to execute an AutoIt script via Python using `os.system()`. However, the program freezes and crashes without any error code. When I am executing the AutoIt script manually it works fine.

Python code:

```
def main():                   
    Exe_file_dir = "C:\\Users\\matan\\Downloads\\npp.8.2.Installer.x64.exe"
    os.system("C:\\Users\\matan\\Desktop\\14th\\gal\\The_project\\startAutoIt\\RealMain.exe 
              " + "Record@"+Exe_file_dir)
```

Autoit code:

```
#RequireAdmin
#include <Array.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GuiButton.au3>
#include ".\RecordMain.au3"
#include ".\RunMain.au3"
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>


Main()

Func Main()
If $CmdLine[0] > 0 Then
   If $CmdLine[1] <> @ScriptName Then
      $mode = $CmdLine[1]
;~    $dir = $CmdLine[2] ;Now, you can use the variable $PAR in your script.
      $parmeters = StringSplit($mode,'@')
      $mode = $parmeters[1]
      $dir = $parmeters[2]
   Endif
Endif


If $mode = 'Record' Then     ;RecordMode
      RecordMain($dir)
ElseIf $mode = 'Run' Then    ;RunMode
      RunMain($dir)
EndIf
;~     Global $aFileList[0]         ;Reset file list


EndFunc
```

This the Autoit function I run:

```
Func RecordMain($sFile)     ; Open the installation, and get controls that user click on them until the instalatin ended.
    Opt("MouseCoordMode", 2)                                        ; Change relative Coords of Mouse to the active window
    _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLDOWN_EVENT, "MouseWheel_Events") ; MouseWheelEvents start
    _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLUP_EVENT, "MouseWheel_Events")   ; MouseWheelEvents start

    If (Not StringInStr($sFile, ".msi") = 0  Or  Not StringInStr($sFile, ".MSI") = 0) Then;if it msi fie
        $iPID = Run("msiexec /i "&$sFile)
        $sLog = StringReplace($sFile, ".msi", ".txt")                   ; Name for log file.
    Else    ;if it exe file
        $iPID = Run($sFile)
        $sLog = StringReplace($sFile, "exe", "txt")                     ; Name for log file.
    EndIf

    _FileCreate($sLog)                                              ; Create log file. locate in the wizard location
    Global $hFileOpen = FileOpen($sLog, $FO_APPEND)                 ; Open log file
    Global $hDLL = DllOpen("user32.dll")                            ; For _IsPressed func
    While 1
        If _IsPressed("01", $hDLL) Then                             ; When mouse click
            $sWinIdentify = WinIdentify()                           ; Identify the window
            $sReturn = GetControlOnMouse(WinGetHandle("[ACTIVE]"))  ; Get Control On Mouse
;~            MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Title", $sReturn, 10)
            If Not $sReturn = False Then                                ; When have control
                FileWrite($hFileOpen, $sWinIdentify & $sReturn & @CRLF) ; Write data to file
             EndIf
            While _IsPressed("01", $hDLL)
                Sleep(100)
;~              MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Title", "sleep", 10)
             WEnd
         EndIf

        If Not ProcessExists($iPID) Then ;check if the file stil open
;~          MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Title", "before", 10)
            ExitLoop
         EndIf
      WEnd

    DllClose($hDLL)
    FileClose($hFileOpen)                                           ; Close log file
    _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLDOWN_EVENT)                  ; MouseWheelEvents stop
    _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLUP_EVENT)                    ; MouseWheelEvents stop
EndFunc
```

Comment: If you want more control over the child, consider `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system`. in particular, that'll give you the option for the Python script to not block waiting for AutoIt to exit; and it'll also let you improve your security posture (using string concatenation to generate shell command lines is an unsafe practice).

Comment: did you run in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error messages?

Comment: I checked and there is no error messages. Its look like the operation system kill the process by force.

Comment: I tired to use `subprocess.Popen` but I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue and copied your Python code and create stub functions for AutoIt functions *(see code snippets and possible solution below)*.

First of all, current version of `main()` Python function has syntax error (the quotation mark should be on the first line in call `os.system()`. I didn't manage to edit description). Check your local code (use double backslashes as editor suggested you.). *But this is not a cause of issue because you would have seen the error "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" in terminal*

As you said, manually running AutoIt script works fine and you don't see any error in terminal. So I guess that cause in executing of `RealMain.exe` file. Some antivirus apps block execution of such executable files that operates with ***important*** files and folders (user Downloads folder in your case). *For example when I tested your code my Windows Security app suggested me to send them this compiled .exe (by `Aut2exe.exe` utility) and check it.* You could miss a blocking notification from your antivirus.

Try to substitute your `.exe` file to not compiled `.au3` file and check result. i.e.

```py
os.system("D:\\tmp\\tmp_autoit\\RealMain.au3 " 
+ "Record@"+Exe_file_dir)
```

But don't forget that default shell behaviour for `.au3` files must be 'Run', not 'Edit'. You can check it in advance by double clicking on `RealMain.au3` file. But watch for antivirus notification, because `AutoIt3.exe` also can be blocked.

Also check carefully how and where you run your Python script *(adding `if __name__ == "__main__":` block at the end of script is a good practice)*.

My code snippets to quick reproduce:

```py
# run_real_main_script.py
import os


def main():                   
    Exe_file_dir = "D:\\tmp\\tmp_autoit\\Sample.log"
    os.system("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Downloads\\RealMain.exe " 
    + "Record@"+Exe_file_dir)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```
;~ RunMain.au3
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Func RunMain($sFile)
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Run RunMain() function" & @CRLF & "$sFile=" & $sFile)
EndFunc
```

```
;~ RecordMain.au3
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Func RecordMain($sFile)
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "", "Run RecordMain() function" & @CRLF & "$sFile=" & $sFile)
EndFunc
```

`RealMain.au3` is the exact copy of "Autoit code:" snippet in the description.

I executed `run_real_main_script.py` script with installed Python 3.9.2 interpreter in PowerShell as:

```
python "D:\tmp\tmp_autoit\check_scripts\run_real_main_script.py"
```